# MVC pattern with child windows

Tags: java, swing

In Java I have a simple window with a button. When I press the button I call the constructor of another class which opens a new window with a button again. 
1) is correct to call a method of the View class from the Model class with the Observer Observable pattern?
2) is correct to delegate the call of the new window to the View class? or I have to do it in the Model class?
3) how can I set a listener for the new button in the Controller class? at the moment I call the constructor of the Controller class, I have an instance of the View (with the first button) but I still not have an instance of the sub-window class (and so the second button).

View:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;
import javax.swing.*;

public class View implements Observer
{
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    JButton button;

    Model model;

    public View(Model model)
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new JPanel();
        button = new JButton("Press");
        this.model = model;

        panel.add(button);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500,500); 
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void update(Observable ob, Object extra_arg)
    {
        switch(model.method_var)
        {
            case 0:
                NewWindow newwindow = new NewWindow();
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
import java.util.Observable;

public class Model extends Observable
{
    int method_var;

    public void newwindow()
    {
        method_var = 0;
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Controller 
{
    Model model;
    View view;

    public Controller(Model model, View view)
    {
        this.model = model;
        this.view = view;

        view.button.addActionListener(new Action());

        model.addObserver(view);
    }

    class Action implements java.awt.event.ActionListener 
    {        
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            model.newwindow();
        }
    }

}
```

New-Window:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class NewWindow 
{
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    JButton button;

    Model model;

    public NewWindow()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new JPanel();
        button = new JButton("Press again");
        this.model = model;

        panel.add(button);
        frame.setSize(100,100); 
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Main:

```
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Model model = new Model();
        View view = new View(model);
        Controller controller = new Controller(model, view);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, all the logic should be in the controllers of the components. That's their purpose. Doing so requires more effort, but it also avoids confusion as your design grows.